# How to skip first several lines of Excel sheet in Python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am able to successfully un-merge all cells in Excel sheet using `openpyxl`; however, I would like to keep the first 7 lines of the sheet intact. As shown below, the first 7 lines contain merged cells.

[image: Upper excel sheet]

After I run the following code (which finds merged cells and splits them):

```
def fill_in(rows,first_cell,last_cell):
    #Take first cell's value
    first_value = first_cell.value
    #Copy and fill/assign this value into each cell of the range
    for tmp in rows:  
        cell = tmp[0]
        print(cell) ##E.g. (<Cell 'Sheet1'.A1>,)  
        print(cell.value) ##E.g. Order Records
        cell.value = first_value 

wb2 = load_workbook('Example.xlsx')
sheets = wb2.sheetnames ##list of sheetnames
for i,sheet in enumerate(sheets): ##for each sheet
    ws = wb2[sheets[i]]
    range_list = ws.merged_cell_ranges
    for _range in range_list:
        first_cell = ws[_range.split(':')[0]] #first cell of each range
        last_cell = ws[_range.split(':')[1]]
        rows = ws[_range] #big set of sets; each cell within each range
        fill_in(list(rows),first_cell,last_cell)
```

For reference, `rows` looks like this:
`((<Cell 'Sheet1'.A1>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.B1>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.C1>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.D1>, <Cell 'Sheet1'.E1>),)`

This is what the new Excel sheet looks like: *the top 7 lines get disordered and messy.*

[image: Results of Upper Excel sheet]

Considering my code above, what can I include/do to skip the first 7 lines of Excel sheet or exclude those lines from being un-merged?

Answer (score 2):

`merged_cell_ranges` is a list, so you just have to start your iteration after index 30 (6 rows * 5 colums)

```
for _range in range_list[30:]:
```

Comment: @ masterfloda - I tried your answer, but it does not work. It rather does the opposite of what I want the code to do -- the first 7 lines remain intact as unmerged, BUT the remaining lines stay merged. What could the problem be?

Comment: @ masterfloda - I also tried printing out `range_list[11:]`, but I only get the first 8 items of the list as an output. Are you sure ws.merged_cell_ranges is a list?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('C:/Users/rschuell/Desktop/Data.xlsx')
df = xls.parse('Data', skiprows=4, index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
print(df)
```